# Google Combo Chart with multiple series, how to add custom HTML Tooltip

Tags: charts, google-visualization, iccube-reporting

I've Google combo chart and like to add a Tooltip.  The icCube documention has an example how to add a HTML tooltip but this will not work for series, only the last item in the serie gets the tooltip. I found an answer how to do this, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17924826/6825710).

But how can I achieve this in icCube?

Answer (score 5):

for google charts, you can reference the [Data Format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#data-format) of the specific chart

for most, the tooltip follows the series column

to have multiple series, each with it's own *custom html tooltip*,
**add a column after each series column**

**NOTE**: *for custom html tooltips to work, the following must be in place...*

the column must have property --> `html: true`

`dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {html: true}});`

and the configuration options must include...

`tooltip: {isHtml: true}`

*see following working snippet*, the tooltip columns are loaded initially as `null`

then the tooltip is built based on the values in the series columns

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(container);

    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', label: 'Year'});

    // series 0
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'number', label: 'Category A'});
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {html: true}});

    // series 1
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'number', label: 'Category B'});
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {html: true}});

    // series 2
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'number', label: 'Category C'});
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {html: true}});

    dataTable.addRows([
      ['2014', 1000, null, 2000, null, 3000, null],
      ['2015', 2000, null, 4000, null, 6000, null],
      ['2016', 3000, null, 6000, null, 9000, null],
    ]);

    for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      dataTable.setValue(i, 2, getTooltip(i, 1));
      dataTable.setValue(i, 4, getTooltip(i, 3));
      dataTable.setValue(i, 6, getTooltip(i, 5));
    }

    function getTooltip(rowIndex, columnIndex) {
      return '<div class="ggl-tooltip"><span>' +
        dataTable.getValue(rowIndex, 0) + ': </span>' +
        dataTable.getFormattedValue(rowIndex, columnIndex) + '</div>';
    }

    chart.draw(dataTable, {
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
      },
      pointSize: 4,
      seriesType: 'area',
      series: {
        2: {
          pointSize: 12,
          pointShape: {
            type: 'star',
            sides: 5,
            dent: 0.6
          },
          type: 'scatter'
        }
      },
      tooltip: {isHtml: true}
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```css
.ggl-tooltip {
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  font-size: 10pt;
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
}

.ggl-tooltip span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: when you do `addColumn` how does computer know which tooltip column corresponds to which series? You setup your tool columns with a tooltip role but without choosing which column to represent. Is it just about their order?

Comment: I see. This is not obvious.