# Google charts tooltip for all lines

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to add tooltip text for each of serioes for my line chart using google chart, but my tooltip works just for latest line, rest of lines use "default" tooltip. Do you know how to solve it?

Default tooltip is not "good" for my usage.

I can't use same "x" point for each series because these are measured data during long time and unfortunately at different time in day and I want to show these data and compare them in latest four weeks (so I have to move monday data to monday x-axis and to have it nice label them by correct tooltip description).

Thanks
Tomáš

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Grafy</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="chart_ico.png">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTempHum);


        function drawTempHum() 
        {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            data.addColumn('datetime', 'X');
            data.addColumn('number', '22 - 22');
            data.addColumn('number', '15 - 21');
            data.addColumn('number', '08 - 14');
            data.addColumn('number', '01 - 07');
            data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
            data.addRows(
            [

                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 0, 4, 33), 10.8, null, null, null, 'Pondělí 22 00:04:33'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 2, 9, 9), 9.8, null, null, null, 'Pondělí 22 02:09:09'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 4, 13, 41), 8.2, null, null, null, 'Pondělí 22 04:13:41'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 6, 18, 7), 6.9, null, null, null, 'Pondělí 22 06:18:07'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 8, 22, 39), 11.9, null, null, null, 'Pondělí 22 08:22:39'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 10, 27, 26), 17.0, null, null, null, 'Pondělí 22 10:27:26'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 12, 32, 14), 18.3, null, null, null, 'Pondělí 22 12:32:14'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 0, 3, 3), null, 9.0, null, null, 'Pondělí 15 00:03:03'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 2, 7, 29), null, 8.5, null, null, 'Pondělí 15 02:07:29'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 4, 11, 49), null, 6.8, null, null, 'Pondělí 15 04:11:49'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 6, 16, 5), null, 5.6, null, null, 'Pondělí 15 06:16:05'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 8, 20, 21), null, 8.2, null, null, 'Pondělí 15 08:20:21'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 10, 24, 56), null, 12.7, null, null, 'Pondělí 15 10:24:56'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 12, 29, 42), null, 19.9, null, null, 'Pondělí 15 12:29:42'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 14, 34, 22), null, 13.9, null, null, 'Pondělí 15 14:34:22'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 16, 38, 54), null, 13.1, null, null, 'Pondělí 15 16:38:54'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 18, 43, 29), null, 12.0, null, null, 'Pondělí 15 18:43:29'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 20, 48, 4), null, 10.4, null, null, 'Pondělí 15 20:48:04'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 22, 52, 31), null, 8.2, null, null, 'Pondělí 15 22:52:31'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 0, 56, 40), null, 5.8, null, null, 'Úterý 16 00:56:40'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 3, 0, 51), null, 4.0, null, null, 'Úterý 16 03:00:51'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 5, 4, 59), null, 2.9, null, null, 'Úterý 16 05:04:59'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 7, 9, 0), null, 2.7, null, null, 'Úterý 16 07:09:00'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 9, 13, 35), null, 10.7, null, null, 'Úterý 16 09:13:35'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 11, 18, 15), null, 22.0, null, null, 'Úterý 16 11:18:15'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 13, 22, 56), null, 20.3, null, null, 'Úterý 16 13:22:56'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 15, 27, 44), null, 16.2, null, null, 'Úterý 16 15:27:44'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 17, 32, 24), null, 15.1, null, null, 'Úterý 16 17:32:24'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 19, 37, 2), null, 13.6, null, null, 'Úterý 16 19:37:02'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 21, 41, 36), null, 11.5, null, null, 'Úterý 16 21:41:36'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 23, 46, 13), null, 9.4, null, null, 'Úterý 16 23:46:13'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 1, 50, 33), null, 7.7, null, null, 'Středa 17 01:50:33'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 3, 54, 58), null, 7.1, null, null, 'Středa 17 03:54:58'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 5, 59, 16), null, 5.7, null, null, 'Středa 17 05:59:16'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 8, 3, 35), null, 6.0, null, null, 'Středa 17 08:03:35'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 10, 8, 0), null, 8.3, null, null, 'Středa 17 10:08:00'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 12, 12, 40), null, 15.5, null, null, 'Středa 17 12:12:40'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 14, 17, 19), null, 14.8, null, null, 'Středa 17 14:17:19'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 16, 21, 58), null, 14.6, null, null, 'Středa 17 16:21:58'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 18, 26, 34), null, 14.1, null, null, 'Středa 17 18:26:34'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 20, 31, 13), null, 12.9, null, null, 'Středa 17 20:31:13'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 22, 35, 49), null, 11.0, null, null, 'Středa 17 22:35:49'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 0, 40, 19), null, 8.8, null, null, 'Čtvrtek 18 00:40:19'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 2, 44, 44), null, 7.3, null, null, 'Čtvrtek 18 02:44:44'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 4, 48, 55), null, 6.0, null, null, 'Čtvrtek 18 04:48:55'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 6, 53, 13), null, 5.1, null, null, 'Čtvrtek 18 06:53:13'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 8, 57, 41), null, 12.4, null, null, 'Čtvrtek 18 08:57:41'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 11, 2, 29), null, 20.8, null, null, 'Čtvrtek 18 11:02:29'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 13, 7, 11), null, 23.3, null, null, 'Čtvrtek 18 13:07:11'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 15, 11, 57), null, 19.1, null, null, 'Čtvrtek 18 15:11:57'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 17, 16, 44), null, 18.7, null, null, 'Čtvrtek 18 17:16:44'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 19, 21, 25), null, 17.7, null, null, 'Čtvrtek 18 19:21:25'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 21, 26, 6), null, 15.6, null, null, 'Čtvrtek 18 21:26:06'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 23, 30, 44), null, 12.8, null, null, 'Čtvrtek 18 23:30:44'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 1, 35, 19), null, 10.2, null, null, 'Pátek 19 01:35:19'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 3, 39, 47), null, 8.4, null, null, 'Pátek 19 03:39:47'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 5, 44, 4), null, 7.3, null, null, 'Pátek 19 05:44:04'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 7, 48, 29), null, 9.0, null, null, 'Pátek 19 07:48:29'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 9, 53, 15), null, 17.1, null, null, 'Pátek 19 09:53:15'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 11, 57, 55), null, 27.5, null, null, 'Pátek 19 11:57:55'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 14, 2, 43), null, 21.4, null, null, 'Pátek 19 14:02:43'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 16, 7, 30), null, 20.1, null, null, 'Pátek 19 16:07:30'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 18, 12, 18), null, 19.6, null, null, 'Pátek 19 18:12:18'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 20, 17, 6), null, 18.2, null, null, 'Pátek 19 20:17:06'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 22, 21, 47), null, 15.0, null, null, 'Pátek 19 22:21:47'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 0, 26, 26), null, 12.1, null, null, 'Sobota 20 00:26:26'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 2, 31, 2), null, 10.0, null, null, 'Sobota 20 02:31:02'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 4, 35, 34), null, 8.2, null, null, 'Sobota 20 04:35:34'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 6, 40, 0), null, 6.8, null, null, 'Sobota 20 06:40:00'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 8, 44, 37), null, 13.4, null, null, 'Sobota 20 08:44:37'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 10, 49, 19), null, 23.4, null, null, 'Sobota 20 10:49:19'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 12, 54, 5), null, 28.1, null, null, 'Sobota 20 12:54:05'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 14, 58, 59), null, 22.0, null, null, 'Sobota 20 14:58:59'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 17, 3, 47), null, 21.2, null, null, 'Sobota 20 17:03:47'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 19, 8, 35), null, 19.7, null, null, 'Sobota 20 19:08:35'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 21, 13, 23), null, 17.4, null, null, 'Sobota 20 21:13:23'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 23, 18, 10), null, 14.9, null, null, 'Sobota 20 23:18:10'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 1, 22, 52), null, 12.3, null, null, 'Neděle 21 01:22:52'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 3, 27, 28), null, 9.7, null, null, 'Neděle 21 03:27:28'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 5, 31, 52), null, 7.7, null, null, 'Neděle 21 05:31:52'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 7, 36, 21), null, 8.5, null, null, 'Neděle 21 07:36:21'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 9, 41, 8), null, 17.5, null, null, 'Neděle 21 09:41:08'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 11, 45, 56), null, 27.3, null, null, 'Neděle 21 11:45:56'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 13, 50, 44), null, 21.2, null, null, 'Neděle 21 13:50:44'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 15, 55, 37), null, 19.3, null, null, 'Neděle 21 15:55:37'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 18, 0, 25), null, 18.6, null, null, 'Neděle 21 18:00:25'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 20, 5, 12), null, 17.3, null, null, 'Neděle 21 20:05:12'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 22, 9, 52), null, 14.3, null, null, 'Neděle 21 22:09:52'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 0, 3, 45), null, null, 11.3, null, 'Pondělí 08 00:03:45'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 2, 8, 20), null, null, 10.8, null, 'Pondělí 08 02:08:20'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 4, 12, 53), null, null, 9.2, null, 'Pondělí 08 04:12:53'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 6, 17, 20), null, null, 7.9, null, 'Pondělí 08 06:17:20'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 8, 21, 48), null, null, 10.3, null, 'Pondělí 08 08:21:48'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 10, 26, 29), null, null, 16.6, null, 'Pondělí 08 10:26:29'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 12, 31, 16), null, null, 24.9, null, 'Pondělí 08 12:31:16'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 14, 36, 3), null, null, 18.8, null, 'Pondělí 08 14:36:03'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 16, 40, 42), null, null, 17.9, null, 'Pondělí 08 16:40:42'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 18, 45, 29), null, null, 17.1, null, 'Pondělí 08 18:45:29'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 20, 50, 11), null, null, 15.7, null, 'Pondělí 08 20:50:11'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 22, 54, 49), null, null, 13.9, null, 'Pondělí 08 22:54:49'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 0, 59, 25), null, null, 11.7, null, 'Úterý 09 00:59:25'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 3, 3, 58), null, null, 9.9, null, 'Úterý 09 03:03:58'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 5, 8, 26), null, null, 8.5, null, 'Úterý 09 05:08:26'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 7, 12, 51), null, null, 7.8, null, 'Úterý 09 07:12:51'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 9, 17, 23), null, null, 11.7, null, 'Úterý 09 09:17:23'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 11, 22, 3), null, null, 17.5, null, 'Úterý 09 11:22:03'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 13, 26, 49), null, null, 19.0, null, 'Úterý 09 13:26:49'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 15, 31, 30), null, null, 18.1, null, 'Úterý 09 15:31:30'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 17, 36, 12), null, null, 17.2, null, 'Úterý 09 17:36:12'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 19, 40, 59), null, null, 15.5, null, 'Úterý 09 19:40:59'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 21, 45, 37), null, null, 13.2, null, 'Úterý 09 21:45:37'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 23, 50, 8), null, null, 11.4, null, 'Úterý 09 23:50:08'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 1, 54, 41), null, null, 9.7, null, 'Středa 10 01:54:41'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 3, 59, 7), null, null, 7.8, null, 'Středa 10 03:59:07'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 6, 3, 34), null, null, 6.8, null, 'Středa 10 06:03:34'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 8, 7, 46), null, null, 6.6, null, 'Středa 10 08:07:46'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 10, 12, 9), null, null, 7.6, null, 'Středa 10 10:12:09'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 12, 16, 50), null, null, 14.7, null, 'Středa 10 12:16:50'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 14, 21, 22), null, null, 13.1, null, 'Středa 10 14:21:22'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 16, 26, 2), null, null, 12.5, null, 'Středa 10 16:26:02'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 18, 30, 35), null, null, 11.0, null, 'Středa 10 18:30:35'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 20, 35, 2), null, null, 10.1, null, 'Středa 10 20:35:02'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 22, 39, 29), null, null, 9.2, null, 'Středa 10 22:39:29'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 0, 43, 55), null, null, 8.0, null, 'Čtvrtek 11 00:43:55'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 2, 48, 20), null, null, 7.3, null, 'Čtvrtek 11 02:48:20'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 4, 52, 41), null, null, 6.8, null, 'Čtvrtek 11 04:52:41'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 6, 57, 1), null, null, 6.1, null, 'Čtvrtek 11 06:57:01'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 9, 1, 11), null, null, 6.2, null, 'Čtvrtek 11 09:01:11'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 11, 5, 32), null, null, 6.6, null, 'Čtvrtek 11 11:05:32'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 13, 9, 50), null, null, 6.0, null, 'Čtvrtek 11 13:09:50'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 15, 14, 1), null, null, 5.3, null, 'Čtvrtek 11 15:14:01'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 17, 18, 17), null, null, 5.2, null, 'Čtvrtek 11 17:18:17'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 19, 22, 34), null, null, 5.6, null, 'Čtvrtek 11 19:22:34'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 21, 26, 50), null, null, 5.4, null, 'Čtvrtek 11 21:26:50'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 23, 31, 1), null, null, 5.3, null, 'Čtvrtek 11 23:31:01'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 1, 35, 14), null, null, 4.9, null, 'Pátek 12 01:35:14'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 3, 39, 26), null, null, 4.3, null, 'Pátek 12 03:39:26'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 5, 43, 29), null, null, 3.6, null, 'Pátek 12 05:43:29'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 7, 47, 38), null, null, 3.5, null, 'Pátek 12 07:47:38'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 9, 51, 43), null, null, 3.9, null, 'Pátek 12 09:51:43'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 11, 55, 56), null, null, 4.3, null, 'Pátek 12 11:55:56'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 14, 0, 9), null, null, 4.4, null, 'Pátek 12 14:00:09'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 16, 4, 17), null, null, 4.8, null, 'Pátek 12 16:04:17'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 18, 8, 37), null, null, 5.0, null, 'Pátek 12 18:08:37'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 20, 12, 44), null, null, 4.6, null, 'Pátek 12 20:12:44'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 22, 16, 55), null, null, 4.2, null, 'Pátek 12 22:16:55'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 0, 21, 4), null, null, 3.8, null, 'Sobota 13 00:21:04'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 2, 25, 12), null, null, 3.3, null, 'Sobota 13 02:25:12'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 4, 29, 2), null, null, 2.6, null, 'Sobota 13 04:29:02'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 6, 33, 4), null, null, 2.1, null, 'Sobota 13 06:33:04'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 8, 37, 7), null, null, 2.0, null, 'Sobota 13 08:37:07'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 10, 41, 4), null, null, 2.4, null, 'Sobota 13 10:41:04'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 12, 45, 10), null, null, 3.0, null, 'Sobota 13 12:45:10'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 14, 49, 20), null, null, 3.9, null, 'Sobota 13 14:49:20'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 16, 53, 25), null, null, 4.3, null, 'Sobota 13 16:53:25'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 18, 57, 36), null, null, 4.2, null, 'Sobota 13 18:57:36'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 21, 1, 44), null, null, 4.1, null, 'Sobota 13 21:01:44'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 23, 5, 52), null, null, 4.0, null, 'Sobota 13 23:05:52'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 1, 9, 58), null, null, 3.8, null, 'Neděle 14 01:09:58'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 3, 14, 4), null, null, 3.7, null, 'Neděle 14 03:14:04'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 5, 18, 2), null, null, 3.9, null, 'Neděle 14 05:18:02'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 7, 22, 3), null, null, 4.0, null, 'Neděle 14 07:22:03'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 9, 26, 22), null, null, 6.4, null, 'Neděle 14 09:26:22'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 11, 30, 50), null, null, 15.1, null, 'Neděle 14 11:30:50'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 13, 35, 23), null, null, 14.1, null, 'Neděle 14 13:35:23'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 15, 39, 58), null, null, 13.5, null, 'Neděle 14 15:39:58'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 17, 44, 33), null, null, 13.5, null, 'Neděle 14 17:44:33'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 19, 49, 8), null, null, 12.5, null, 'Neděle 14 19:49:08'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 21, 53, 41), null, null, 10.8, null, 'Neděle 14 21:53:41'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 23, 58, 11), null, null, 9.5, null, 'Neděle 14 23:58:11'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 20, 50, 3), null, null, null, 9.5, 'Pondělí 01 20:50:03'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 1, 22, 54, 35), null, null, null, 8.0, 'Pondělí 01 22:54:35'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 0, 59, 0), null, null, null, 6.2, 'Úterý 02 00:59:00'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 3, 3, 18), null, null, null, 4.6, 'Úterý 02 03:03:18'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 5, 7, 32), null, null, null, 3.5, 'Úterý 02 05:07:32'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 7, 11, 42), null, null, null, 2.8, 'Úterý 02 07:11:42'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 9, 15, 37), null, null, null, 6.3, 'Úterý 02 09:15:37'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 11, 20, 14), null, null, null, 11.8, 'Úterý 02 11:20:14'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 13, 24, 57), null, null, null, 16.3, 'Úterý 02 13:24:57'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 15, 29, 41), null, null, null, 16.9, 'Úterý 02 15:29:41'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 17, 34, 25), null, null, null, 16.4, 'Úterý 02 17:34:25'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 19, 39, 8), null, null, null, 15.3, 'Úterý 02 19:39:08'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 21, 43, 44), null, null, null, 13.0, 'Úterý 02 21:43:44'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 2, 23, 48, 21), null, null, null, 11.5, 'Úterý 02 23:48:21'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 1, 52, 56), null, null, null, 10.5, 'Středa 03 01:52:56'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 3, 57, 29), null, null, null, 9.9, 'Středa 03 03:57:29'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 6, 2, 3), null, null, null, 10.4, 'Středa 03 06:02:03'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 8, 6, 32), null, null, null, 11.0, 'Středa 03 08:06:32'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 10, 11, 16), null, null, null, 14.2, 'Středa 03 10:11:16'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 12, 16, 0), null, null, null, 22.0, 'Středa 03 12:16:00'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 14, 20, 42), null, null, null, 19.7, 'Středa 03 14:20:42'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 16, 25, 30), null, null, null, 18.8, 'Středa 03 16:25:30'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 18, 30, 16), null, null, null, 17.5, 'Středa 03 18:30:16'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 20, 35, 2), null, null, null, 15.0, 'Středa 03 20:35:02'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 3, 22, 39, 45), null, null, null, 13.6, 'Středa 03 22:39:45'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 0, 44, 26), null, null, null, 13.4, 'Čtvrtek 04 00:44:26'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 2, 49, 1), null, null, null, 12.7, 'Čtvrtek 04 02:49:01'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 4, 53, 39), null, null, null, 11.8, 'Čtvrtek 04 04:53:39'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 6, 58, 16), null, null, null, 11.3, 'Čtvrtek 04 06:58:16'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 9, 3, 1), null, null, null, 14.7, 'Čtvrtek 04 09:03:01'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 11, 7, 46), null, null, null, 20.2, 'Čtvrtek 04 11:07:46'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 13, 12, 33), null, null, null, 22.8, 'Čtvrtek 04 13:12:33'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 15, 17, 20), null, null, null, 19.6, 'Čtvrtek 04 15:17:20'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 17, 22, 8), null, null, null, 18.7, 'Čtvrtek 04 17:22:08'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 19, 26, 54), null, null, null, 17.4, 'Čtvrtek 04 19:26:54'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 21, 31, 41), null, null, null, 15.7, 'Čtvrtek 04 21:31:41'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 4, 23, 36, 25), null, null, null, 14.4, 'Čtvrtek 04 23:36:25'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 1, 41, 8), null, null, null, 13.5, 'Pátek 05 01:41:08'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 3, 45, 43), null, null, null, 12.5, 'Pátek 05 03:45:43'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 5, 50, 15), null, null, null, 11.6, 'Pátek 05 05:50:15'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 7, 54, 51), null, null, null, 11.8, 'Pátek 05 07:54:51'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 9, 59, 39), null, null, null, 17.9, 'Pátek 05 09:59:39'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 12, 4, 27), null, null, null, 25.3, 'Pátek 05 12:04:27'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 14, 9, 14), null, null, null, 22.5, 'Pátek 05 14:09:14'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 16, 14, 2), null, null, null, 21.6, 'Pátek 05 16:14:02'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 18, 18, 56), null, null, null, 20.4, 'Pátek 05 18:18:56'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 20, 23, 43), null, null, null, 18.5, 'Pátek 05 20:23:43'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 5, 22, 28, 31), null, null, null, 16.3, 'Pátek 05 22:28:31'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 0, 33, 15), null, null, null, 14.4, 'Sobota 06 00:33:15'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 2, 37, 48), null, null, null, 13.3, 'Sobota 06 02:37:48'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 4, 42, 32), null, null, null, 12.7, 'Sobota 06 04:42:32'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 6, 47, 5), null, null, null, 12.5, 'Sobota 06 06:47:05'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 8, 51, 45), null, null, null, 12.2, 'Sobota 06 08:51:45'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 10, 56, 19), null, null, null, 12.2, 'Sobota 06 10:56:19'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 13, 0, 55), null, null, null, 13.2, 'Sobota 06 13:00:55'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 15, 5, 33), null, null, null, 13.0, 'Sobota 06 15:05:33'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 17, 10, 17), null, null, null, 13.6, 'Sobota 06 17:10:17'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 19, 14, 49), null, null, null, 12.2, 'Sobota 06 19:14:49'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 21, 19, 21), null, null, null, 10.8, 'Sobota 06 21:19:21'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 6, 23, 23, 51), null, null, null, 8.7, 'Sobota 06 23:23:51'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 1, 28, 16), null, null, null, 7.2, 'Neděle 07 01:28:16'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 3, 32, 36), null, null, null, 6.0, 'Neděle 07 03:32:36'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 5, 36, 55), null, null, null, 5.2, 'Neděle 07 05:36:55'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 7, 41, 8), null, null, null, 5.4, 'Neděle 07 07:41:08'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 9, 45, 38), null, null, null, 13.4, 'Neděle 07 09:45:38'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 11, 50, 24), null, null, null, 25.0, 'Neděle 07 11:50:24'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 13, 55, 11), null, null, null, 21.9, 'Neděle 07 13:55:11'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 15, 59, 53), null, null, null, 20.5, 'Neděle 07 15:59:53'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 18, 4, 40), null, null, null, 19.6, 'Neděle 07 18:04:40'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 20, 9, 27), null, null, null, 16.8, 'Neděle 07 20:09:27'],
                [new Date(2019, 4, 7, 22, 14, 7), null, null, null, 14.3, 'Neděle 07 22:14:07'],
            ]);

            var options = 
            {
                interpolateNulls: true,
                //title: 'Snimac 6 Teplota a Vlhkost',
                width: 1200,
                height: 600,
                chartArea: 
                {
                    left: 80, 
                    bottom: 80, 
                    width: '87%', 
                    height: '85%',
                    backgroundColor: 
                    {
                        stroke: '#f0f0ff',
                        strokeWidth: 1,
                    },
                },
                series: {

                    0: {targetAxisIndex: 0, lineWidth:5, tooltip: true},
                    1: {targetAxisIndex: 0, tooltip: true},
                    2: {targetAxisIndex: 0, tooltip: true},
                    3: {targetAxisIndex: 0, tooltip: true},
                },
                vAxes: {
                    0: {title: 'Teplota (°C)'},
                },
                hAxes: {

                        0: {title: 'Den', format:'EE HH'},
                },
                legend: { position: 'bottom' },
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('TempHumChart'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }



    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Sensor name: Venek</h1>
    <h2>

    </h2>   
    <table class="columns">
        <tr>
            <td><div id="TempHumChart" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <br>
<br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add a tooltip column after each series column, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39469316/5090771)...

Comment: Thank you, it works, it is simple when you know how to do it.